# images are blurry on tablet

Tags: android, android-layout

I have developed an app with images, however, the images look blurry when I run the application from a tablet. The tablet size is 10.1.

When I run the application on mobile devices it works like charm, can you please advice why the pictures look blurry on the tablet. I have created drawable folders

for each of the different screen sizes which has also not fixed the problem. Please can you help or advice?.

My Drawable folder structure and sizes

- drawable-hdpi - Width 62 x Height 62
- drawable- mdpi - Width 40 x Height 40
- drawable- xhdpi - Width 82 x Height 82
- drawable - xxhdpi - Width 123 x Height 123
- drawable- xxxhdpi - Width 164 x Height 164

Is this correct, Please advice?

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/placesbtn"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_place"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="83dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="83dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/flipper1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="Places"
        android:focusable="true"  />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/transportbtn"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_travels"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/placesbtn"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/placesbtn"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/placesbtn"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:contentDescription="Travel" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/directionbtn"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_direction"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/placesbtn"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/placesbtn"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:contentDescription="Direction"  />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/gallerybtn"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_gallerys"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/directionbtn"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/directionbtn"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/directionbtn"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:contentDescription="Gallery" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ogranize your post into the table i created, too hard to read it when its formatted like that

Comment: which table you created.

Comment: Also what images are blurry?  Is your app icon or what exactly?

Comment: imagebuttons, I have now placed them in the question section. please help?

Comment: have you ever found a solution for that? i have same problem

Answer (score 1):

You are applying explicit sizes to your `ImageButton` images without defining the `ScaleType` the underlying `ImageView` will use to scale them to that size.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

You should do one of the following:

1. Use `wrap_content` in your layout width and height.
2. Use `ScaleType` of `center`
3. Use larger images so that you don't need to scale them up.

Comment: can you  give me an example of what size images shall I use.

Comment: You are forcing your Images to be 150x100dp, so that seems like a good starting place. Your image are 40x40dp, so they are being scaled up to 150x100dp.